# Delete line with batch script when testing only the first 4 characters on the line

Tags: batch-file, find

How can I search in lines in the batch file.
And only if the first 4 chararcters start with `SLUI` or `VRLP` then the line must be deleted.

Now I have the following commands in script, only the line will also be deleted if somewhere else in the line `SLUI` or `VRLP` exist:

```bash
set "prsc=prsc.txt"
if not exist "%prsc%" exit /b

copy /y "%prsc%" "%prsc_bup.txt%" >nul 2>&1 || exit /b
find /v "vrlp"< "%prsc_bup.txt%" >"%prsc%" 

copy /y "%prsc%" "%prsc.weg%" >nul 2>&1 || exit /b
find /v "sluit"< "%prsc.weg%" >"%prsc%" 

del "%prsc.weg%"
```

Answer (score 1):

```all-bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"
 
=;( findstr /bvi "vrlp sluit" <.\"prsc.txt"  
=;) 1>.\"del.tmp"

=;( move /y .\"del.tmp" .\"prsc.txt" 
=;) 1>nul 2>&1 & exit /b
```

---

- Filter lines that do not start withstart with **`SLUI` or `VRLP` case sensitive**

```bash
findstr /bv "SLUI VRLP" <.\prsc.txt
```

---

- Filter lines that do not start with **`SLUI` or `VRLP` case insensitive**

```bash
findstr /bvi "vrlp sluit" <.\prsc.txt
```

---

- Now, if you want to obtain lines by filtering the strings and keeping the blank lines without discarding, it gets a little complicated:

```bash
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"
 
=;( for /f "usebackq tokens=1*delims=:]" %%i in =;(`
        findstr /nbvi "vrlp sluit" ^<.\"prsc.txt" `);= do echo/%%~j
=;) 1>.\"del.tmp"

=;( move /y .\"del.tmp" .\"prsc.txt" =;) 1>nul 2>&1 & exit /b
```

---

> *... only the line will also be deleted if **somewhere** else in the line **SLUI** or **VRLP** exist:*
>
> - So just remove the `findstr /B` flag, since this is what treats/limits the filter from operating at the `/Beginning` of the line:
>
> ---
>
> ```bash
> @echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"
>  
> =;( for /f "usebackq tokens=1*delims=:]" %%i in =;(`
>     findstr /nvi "vrlp sluit" ^<.\"prsc.txt" ` 
> =;) do echo/%%~j
> =;) 1>.\"del.tmp"
>
> =;( move /y .\"del.tmp" .\"prsc.txt" 
> =;) 1>nul 2>&1 & exit /b
> ```

---

## Additional resources:

- [`Cd` | `ChDir`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`FindSTR /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [`Move /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Escape Characters](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

---

Comment: lo-ol - Thanks for the useful batch script and instructions.